# main.cppy9.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `add(int, int)'

Tags: c++, header-files

```
#include <iostream>
#include "add.h"
#include "sub.h"
#include "Mult.h"
#include "div.h"
#include "mod.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {
  int a,b;
  cout << "Enter a number: ";
  cin >> a >> b;


add(a,b);
sub(a,b);
Mult(a,b);
div(a,b);
mod(a,b); 
  return 0;
}
```

```
#include "add.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void add(int a, int b) 
{ 
    cout << "Addition value = " << a + b << endl; 
}
```

```
#ifndef add_include
#define add_include



void add(int , int ); 



#endif
```

i am using dev-c++ when i wrote the program the fist time it worked then i saved it and closed and tried running the program second time it give this 
    main.cppy9.cpp:(.text+0x4b): undefined reference to `add(int, int)' 
    main.cppy9.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to`sub(int, int)'
    main.cppy9.cpp:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `Mult(int, int)'
    main.cppy9.cpp:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to`div(int, int)'
    main.cppy9.cpp:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to `mod(int, int)'

```
    C:\crossdev\src\mingw-w64-v3-git\mingw-w64-crt\crt\crt0_c.c undefined reference to `WinMain'
```

Comment: You need to compile all you cpp files together.  That would look like `g++ main.cpp add.cpp div.pp ...(rest of cpp file)`

Comment: You must configure your IDE to compiler and link all `.cpp` files.

Comment: You say it worked one time, so try to clear the build artefacts and make a clean build. And think about using a halfway modern IDE and/or compiler.